# Can not add XAML breakpoint in Silverlight 5 project using Visual Studio 2012 RTM

Tags: c#, silverlight, debugging, xaml, visual-studio-2012

So the problem is when i try to setup breakpoint on line with Binding markup extension I get error telling me that it's unable to set breakpoint in this location.

**Visual Studio**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709
Installed Version: Ultimate
```

**Platform settings**

[image: B]

Platform targets are x86 for all except Silverlight ( selection box locked there)

Debug info is set to full everywhere.

**Debug settings**
[image]

Cleaned up and rebuild solution with no errors.

Go to line with Binding press F9 or Debug->Toggle breakpoint and see:

[image]

Comment: Your assembly reference is not what you think it is? Or you're compiling in Release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had this I error I could usually solve it by doing the following things:

- Make sure that Silverlight debugging is enabled: `Project properties -> Web -> Debuggers -> Activate the` **Silverlight** `CheckBox.`
- Use the **Internet Explorer for debugging**. Although *it may* work with other browsers, I often ran into strange problems like the Breakpoints not being correctly set.

Most important:

- **Clear the IE browser cache**. It is most likely possible that the browser has cached an older version of your Silverlight application and for some reason does not use the latest version of it.
- If this works for you, you miht also consider to configure the caching of the temporary internet files to "Never" to make sure that IE always uses the most recent version of your SL application.

Comment: Sorry, hot helped. Edited the post with more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more details for a accurate solution. By experience, you should try:

1 - Check the Configuration Manager and assert all projects are building for Debug, and targeting x86. (x64 has some debugging limitations).

2 - In Project Properties Page > Build > Advanced, assert Debug Info is set to full.

3 - Clean and rebuild your solution. (Worked for me on ASP.NET).

Also, when I couldn't solve this problem, i used a workaround; Create an event handler for DataBind event, and break the code there. Then step into. Eventually you'll step into the xaml file.

Please, mark answer if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, hot helped. Edited the post with more info.

Answer (score 1):

The way if i fixed it by selecting Internet Explorer as browser to run into. Then set the binding reakpoint while it was running. Since then it is working well.